# "Command timed out waiting for send" in WindowsPhoneTestFramework

Tags: windows-phone, wp7test

a couple of questions:

1.When I open an app in the emuhost commandline, I can open, close, install, uninstall it, but I can't interact with it (tap on something etc.), it says:

> ```
> Next action? 
> invokeTap HitThisButton
> -> Command timed out waiting for send
> WCF command messages ->: Timeout 
> invokeTap:False
> ```

Even the ping says Active: False. Any ideas?

2.The doFlick command is commented out due to something with Nokia Music. Why is it so? Is it safe to uncomment the code now?

3.It says in the docs that you can add multiple targets. But in VS, the target device is a dropdown menu, and I've looked in the csproj file, and there is no device field in there. How do you add multiple emulators/devices?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As seen on another site, the problem indeed lies in the hostname ending with .net ("bla.bla.net:8085"). I've worked around it by entering the hosts IP address directly in this [file](https://github.com/Expensify/WindowsPhoneTestFramework/blob/master/Server/WindowsPhoneEmulatorAutomationController/Win8EmulatorWindowsPhoneDeviceController.cs), line 81.

If anybody knows why it is bad for the hostname to end in .net, that would be marvelous.